# Custom copy paste. how to eliminate invalid characters from paste?

Tags: macos, mac, copy-paste, rename, filenames

I collect articles and like having the title of the article in the filename. However, some titles contain invalid characters such as ':'. This precludes a simple, and quick, copy paste operation to create meaningful filenames. Is there a way to prevent the paste from including invalid characters for filenames?